# Is it possible to create new fields in a profile?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, profile

I was wondering if there is a way to create new fields in a profile? For example, could I write an add-in of some sort that put a PGP or S/MIME encryption key in my profile and make it part of the public profile?

I walked through the API documentation and these forums and I didn't see a way to make this happen.

Basically the end-game I want is to use FQL to search for these keys.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a place to stash this sort of generic meta data per user using the Graph API. And that makes sense, when you think about it. Otherwise all kinds of junk could be stored there...

So you would probably need to keep this data on your servers or through an App that the users authorize (and then you could theoretically add it to the graph as some connection, like "userX 'encrypts with' this_public_key")..